# Is there anyway we to get list of processes started by Python?

Tags: python

I wrote an Python code and it as multiple instances of subprocess.Popen and also functions running in different threads. Is there any way I can track all these processes so that at the end of the program I can kill each one.

Comment: Could you use the multiprocessing in Python to create a pool?
https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html
https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers

Answer (score 0):

You may want to maintain a list of processes started by your program. Process id of `subprocess.Popen(...)` can be accessed by `Popen.pid`. You can refer it here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.pid